# Pop up div shinks on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup which will get shrink and the content will dislocate on the browser window resize. I am stuck with this

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/ZjdU4/

and here is the fullscreen fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/ZjdU4/show/

Maybe you could view and check resizing the window

### HTML

```
<div id="popup" >

 <div id="img-section" >
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artdesigner/tweet-my-web/256/single-bird-icon.png" />
        </div>
    <div id="description">
     //text content
    </div>

</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
<a href="#"> click here</a>
```

### CSS

```
.black_overlay {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0%;
     left: 0%;
     min-width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     background-color: black;
     z-index:1001;
     -moz-opacity: 0.8;
     opacity:.80;
     filter: alpha(opacity=80);
 }
 #popup {
     display: none;
     position: fixed;
     top: 8%;
     left: 10%;
     max-width:1200px;
     max-height:600px;
     height:auto;
     width:auto;
     padding: 16px;
     background-color: white;
     z-index:1002;
     overflow:hidden;

  }
 #img-section {
     position:relative;
     width:800px;
     float:left;
     background:black;
     cursor:pointer;
     height:600px;
     padding:5px;
     margin-top: -20px;
     margin-left: -15px;
     margin-right: 10px;

 }
 #description {
     position:relative;
     background-color: #fff;
     max-width:400px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     position: relative;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     max-height:600px;
     height:auto;
     padding: 20px;

 }
 #img-section > img {
     display:inline-block;
     height: auto;
     vertical-align:middle;
     width:auto;
 }
```

I want the poup to remain as it is, It should not shrink

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's exactly how browsers are supposed to work. Maybe you can clarify what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You could resize the browser,it shrinks

Comment: Is it bad that it shrinks? Seems like the sensible thing...

Comment: @Rudie, you could see that the text content comes down as it shrinks

Comment: @SarathSprakash Yes I see. What do you propose we do about that? Shrink the left side too? Shrink nothing (so scrollbars are invisible)? Make the whole document scrollable horizontally? You did give it a MAX-width after all...

Comment: @Rudie I think making the document scrollable horizontally without shrinking works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side scrolling for a popup is horrible, but:

- make the popup `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`
- give the body a `min-width` of left margin + popup width (currently that would be `calc(1200px + 10%)`
- same for height?
- make all `max-width` => `width`, because you know how much room you have

Your existing CSS is mighty strange, but this might do it: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/ZjdU4/1/

Highlights:

```
body {
    min-width: calc(1200px + 10%);
}
.black_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#popup, #popup * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using percentage for your height and width.

The browser change its size on Resize, therefore the value of the percentage depreciates. 
Like 10% of `100px` differs from 10% of `10px`.

Use `px` to keep your height and width the same size on resize.
Of course depending on what you want neither is better than the other

Comment: You're ridiculous. We're here for code not literature